# CentOS 6.5 - After compiling gdal.so: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: gdal, php, centos, drupal, cartaro

CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Linux version 2.6.18-028stab101.1 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)

I'm trying to Install Cartaro CMS (http://cartaro.org/). GeoServer, Postgresql and PostGIS are up and running.

The only missing software requirement to install Cantaro is the GDAL-PHP extension. I've spend hours to resolve the dependencies but after successfully compiling the gdal.so, "make test" fails with the following warning:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/tmp/php5-gdal-0.1.3/modules/gdal.so' - /tmp/php5-gdal-0.1.3/modules/gdal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN17GDALDriverManager10MoveDriverEP10GDALDriveri in Unknown on line 0

- PHP_SAPI    : cli
- PHP_VERSION : 5.4.36
- ZEND_VERSION: 2.4.0
- PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux 268.xxx.de 2.6.18-028stab101.1
- INI actual  : /tmp/php5-gdal-0.1.3/tmp-php.ini
- More .INIs  :
- CWD         : /tmp/php5-gdal-0.1.3
- Extra dirs  :
- VALGRIND    : Not used
- SKIP Test: OGRGeometry [tests/ogrgeometry.phpt]
- FAIL Test: Version number [tests/version.phpt]

I've compiled the actual stable vesions of gdal (1.9.2) and proj4 (4.8.0) by following these instructions:

https://github.com/wavded/ogre/wiki/Compiling-a-recent-ogr2ogr-from-source-on-CentOS-%28RHEL%29